# How do I connect braided under sink hose to 3/8 inch RO plastic tubing?

Tags: plumbing

I can't figure out how to hook up the incoming water to my reverse osmosis system. I want to tap off the braided hose here, and use a quick fit for the plastic tubing but have searched and ordered two parts and can't seem to figure out what is correct.

[image: under sink braided hose]

Answer (score 1):

you need whats called a braided hose adaptor.  see pic attached. [image]